# Integrating Kinematic equatioms with variable initial conditions

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Suppose you have have acceleration and angular velocity for a rigid object but unknown initial orientation, velocity and position.

Can you integrate the known data in such a way that it's easy to update the system when the initial conditions become known?

For position with a fixed orientation it's straightforward but the addition of angular velocity makes it not so clear.

Comment: What do you mean update?

Comment: Update the absolute position and orientation of the system with respect to these new initial conditions.

Comment: So it sounds you ideally want a transformation that takes the old/new initial conditions & system and puts out the new system. Maybe with some algebra I can answer this. Will think about it

Comment: The solution depends in the initial conditions and it is very sensitive to the _exact_ values used for initial conditions. So the quick answer is **no**.

Comment: Looking at this more something called IMU pre integration does and apparently is able to integrate IMU data on its own resulting in a simple term to update.

Comment: I don't understand the first term in the sum of eq 33 though, wouldn't delta.V_i be fixed across the time interval?

Comment: https://limhyungtae.github.io/2022-04-01-IMU-Preintegration-(Easy)-4.-Derivation-of-Preintegrated-IMU-Measurements/